# How can I extract images with negative coordinate values?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm currently trying to extract an bounding box inside of a larger image as shown here:

```
img = cv2.imread(args.data_dir + i[1]["image_id"])

x = int(i[1]['xCenter'])
y = int(i[1]['yCenter'])

x1 = int(i[1]['xCenter'] - patch_direction)
y1 = int(i[1]['yCenter'] - patch_direction)

bbox = img[y1:y1+args.patch_size, x1:x1+args.patch_size]

cv2.imwrite(args.fp_dir + f'{(i[1]["image_id"]).rstrip(".png")}_x_{x}_y_{y}.png', bbox)
```

However, I encounter issues when the `x1` or `y1` coordinates are negative. I'm assuming the issue begins in the bbox array and so was wondering if there is a workaround?

I'm trying to extract a fixed sized box of 32 x 32 from a 512 x 512 image and so will need to 'pad' images that can't be extracted at that size.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible approaches:

- You can extract each patch, cropping it to the edge of the image, then apply padding. You just need to ensure x1 and y1 are positive: `bbox = img[math.max(y1, 0): ...`
- You can pad the whole image and offset coordinates. This is probably better since you already negatively offset `x` and `y` to create `x1` and `y1`. Just pad the image using [np.pad](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) and use `x` and `y` directly:

```py
img = np.pad(img, (patch_direction,)) # This pads before and after on each axis with the same amount
bbox = img[y:y+args.patch_size, x:x+args.patch_size]
```

Edit: You mention in the comments that your image has a shape of `(w, h, 3)`. I assumed you had a greyscale image (2D array). In that case you have to use the more complex version of `np.pad`:

```py
img = np.pad(img, ((patch_direction,patch_direction), (patch_direction,patch_direction), (0,0)))
```

This will avoid padding the final axis (colour channels).

Comment: thanks, however, I get this error when I try to pass any image with the suggested padding from the second solution```cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:801: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite' ```

Comment: Check the shape of the `bbox` before trying to save it. I don't know what `args.patch_size` or `i[1]` contain so if they have invalid values the output shape could be zero.

Comment: ```args.patch_size``` is an int value of 16 pixels. ```i[1]``` contains all pandas df info relating to columns. An example output shape of a set of centroid coordinates with a -ve value looks like this coords: ``` -7, 352``` bbox shape: ```(32, 0, 35)```. The images that aren't padded and don't have an issue have this shape: ```(32, 32, 3)```.

Comment: I've updated my answer. However, I'm not sure if this will necessarily solve your problem: do you mean to say that `i[1]['xCenter']` and `i[1]['yCenter']` may sometimes be negative? If so, how negative? What do you want to happen to them? Should they be completely black?

Comment: yes, it only happens sometimes and varies but won't be more than 16 pixels in each direction (x or y). They can be completely black but I'm also open to other forms of padding like symmetric or reflective etc.

Comment: What is the value of `patch_direction`? I assumed it was enough pad the entire image. Regarding negative values of `x` and `y`, you could simply add 16 to the padding in each direction and add 16 to `x` and `y`.

Comment: it's a small size of 16 pixels. The padding solution didn't work in my case. I've instead opted for offsetting the patch coordinates by the negative coordinate values. So my objects don't necessarily have to be in the centre of the image but somewhere within the designated patch size.